# Console logs from a react application loaded in an ElectronJS container

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am working on an electron application used for display management. The app is used in malls/restaurants/airports for digital display ads. The electron app internally loads a react web-app and then displays it. The react web-app comes from our vendor who has a platform for displaying ads from different vendors. The react web-app is crashing in some instances (it is not able to find the correct ad etc). I am unable to debug this crash because the console.log messages from react web-app are not shown anywhere.

Is there a way to redirect the console.logs from the react application to some file?

Architecture:
- Electron App is a full-screen container for playing any content. 
- Vendor provides a web-app, which plays different ads. This web-app is a react application.
- Vendor web-app crashes, but not able to see those logs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, if you are trying to debug a renderer process you can open dev tools for this by calling the `openDevToos()` method on instances of `webContents`.

This is an example:

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

If you are trying to debug the main process, you should be able to leverage Google Chrome developer tools. If you open chrome and go to: `chrome://inspect`, you should be able to see your electron instance and click "inspect".

There are a few more options, which you can find [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging) but I am of the opinion that these are the two simplest approaches.

I would also suggest leveraging `debugger` statements, as it will halt the execution of the code where you declare a debugger statement, and you could pin point more easily where the crash is happening.